# Python 2: print out the consecutive days in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I have a script that prints out weather information. At the bottom of the script it is meant to print out the next eight days weather summary which it does. however I don't know how to print out consecutive days so the days match the description.

```
import sys
import os
import time
import optparse
import json 
import urllib2

# You'll need an API key below... you get 1000 requests per day for free.

API="APIKEY"
URL="https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"

# Your latitude and longitude belong here, I use SF for example
LAT= 51.752725
LNG= -0.339436

#Direction of the wind
directions = ["N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"]

def bearing_to_direction(bearing):
    d = 360. / 8.
    return directions[int((bearing+d/2)/d)]

now = time.time()

req = urllib2.Request(URL+API+"/"+("%f,%f"%(LAT,LNG))+"?units=uk2")
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
parsed = json.loads(response.read())
f = open("WEATHER.cache", "w")
f.write(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
f.close() ;

c = parsed["currently"]
print ":::", time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime(c["time"]))
print ":::", time.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y\n")
print "::: Conditions:", c["summary"]
print "::: Temperature:", ("%.1f" % c["temperature"])+u"\u00B0C"
print "::: Humidity:", ("%4.1f%%" % (c["humidity"]*100.))
print "::: Wind:", int(round(c["windSpeed"])), "mph", bearing_to_direction(c["windBearing"])

d = parsed["daily"]["data"][0]
print "::: High:", ("%.1f" % d["temperatureMax"])+u"\u00B0C"
print "::: Low:", ("%.1f" % d["temperatureMin"])+u"\u00B0C"

d = parsed["daily"]["data"]

for x in d[1:8]:
    print time.strftime("\t%A:"), ("%.1f" % x["temperatureMax"])+u"\u00B0C -", x["summary"]
```

Every works in the code apart from this section:

```
for x in d[1:8]:
    print time.strftime("\t%A:"), ("%.1f" % x["temperatureMax"])+u"\u00B0C -", x["summary"]
```

At the moment it just prints Thursday with all the eight days description beside it.

```
::: Low: 13.0°C
    Thursday Partly cloudy throughout the day.
    Thursday Partly cloudy throughout the day.
    Thursday Light rain starting in the afternoon.
    Thursday Light rain until afternoon.
    Thursday Drizzle starting in the afternoon, continuing until evening.
    Thursday Light rain until evening.
    Thursday Light rain starting in the afternoon, continuing until evening.
    Thursday Light rain starting in the evening.
```

Comment: This is not even close to enough code. Where is `time` coming from? You really need to read [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `time` (not a good idea using this as a name) into a `datetime` instance, instead of `time` instance, and then you can use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to increment the `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

t = datetime.now()
for i, x in enumerate(d[:12]):
    print (t+timedelta(days=i)).strftime("\t%A:"), x["summary"]
```